# Why should we return deferred.promise()

Tags: jquery

```
function sync(){
    var timer;
    $('#result').html('waiting…');
    var promise = process();
    promise.done(function(a) {
        $('#result').html('done.'+a);
    });
    promise.fail(function(e) {
        $('#result').html('fail.'+e);
    });
}

function process() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
    $.ajax({ 
        url: url,
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            return deferred.resolve(5); // line:1
        },
        error: function(data){
            return deferred.reject(0); // line:2
        }
    });
    return  deferred.promise(); // line:3
}
```

Why should we return `deferred.promise()` in this above code? Suppose if i remove line#3 then I get an error like:

> TypeError: promise is undefined

It should return at `line#1` or `line#2`. Why do we need `line#3` and what is the use of line#3?

> if it is return properly at line#1 or Line#2 then What is the use of line#3 
>   [see the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/bL7tm1y2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function process() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
    $.ajax({ 
        url: url,
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            deferred.resolve(); // line:1
        },
        error: function(data){
            deferred.reject(); // line:2
         }
    });
    return  deferred; // line:3
}
```

do not return anything in callback of $.ajax because the context is "window" inside ajax request.you could try this:

```
function sync(){
     var promise = process();
     promise.done(function() {
         alert('done.');
     });
     promise.fail(function() {
        alert('fail.');
     });
}
function process() {
     var deferred = $.Deferred();
     var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
     setTimeout(function(){
        if(true){
            deferred.resolve();  
        }
     },3000);
     return  deferred; // line:3
}
```

this is an simulation of your example.